# React-Native: Code compiling correctly but screens are empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am fairly new to react native and have been attempting to build a very simple registration app.
Currently I have 2 screens running, the first landingscreen.js includes a button to prompt the first registration screen.

This screen works fine but its title shows as blank. (I am using react-navigator)
Below is the screen and you can find the corresponding code [here](https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/25d815229047112326e45212d11b2b15).
[image]

On clicking the register here button the next screen is prompted which should show two fields an email and password field with the title "Let's create an account". As you can see below , all that works is the next button but I have no compilation errors. The code pertaining to this screen may be accessed [here](https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/adb25968cfe09158abd350f458f72e4d).

[image]

Any help or way pointing would be more than appreciated.
Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change navigation(you have written navigtion) spelling

```
static navigationOptions= {
    title: "Let's make an account",
               }
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my header issue.
Any idea on the fields ?

Comment: Wait let me check.There are three components on the register page two text fields and one button ?

Comment: Yes @Paras Watts

Comment: Why are you using two renders? I am not sure if you can do this.

Comment: Will try and move forward using one render then,
Thanks @Paras Watts 
Will include as answer if it solves the situation

Comment: What you can do is change the render with two text components .

Name that render as renderTextBox()

Then call that render in main render method
like this
{this.renderTextBox()}

Comment: It is ok to use multiple render methods, this way it is easy to divide code and easy to manage different components. But every render should have a different name and then call those render methods in the main render.

Answer (score 0):

The headers not being seen was solved as @Paras Watts noted by fixing a spelling mistake.

To get the fields to show I then put the jsx pertaining to the form in the same render as the navigation also changing any  tags to view to stick to the format of jsx.

Comment: you can also put them in another render and then call that render like other functions in your main render. Please accept my answer if it helped you.